# test electron app with spectron and travis

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, automated-tests, electron, travis-ci

I'm trying to test my electron app https://github.com/rafaelleru/torrent_player with spectron and I try to setup the test of example in https://github.com/electron/spectron ant it pass in my local pc but in travis I don't know how to setup the bin files to test or how tell to travis to generate the bin files.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question if you don't specify exactly what happens. But below is how I solved it, I hope it can be helpful.

**This is how I got Spectron running my Electron application in Travis (Linux only):**

*.travis.yml*

```
os:
  - linux

language: node_js

node_js:
  - "7.7"

before_script:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then export DISPLAY=:99.0; fi
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start; fi
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then sleep 3; fi

script:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - npm install
  - npm run e2e

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: change
```

*utils.js*

```
const electron = require('electron');

const beforeEach = function (env = {}) {
  this.app = new Application({
    path: electron,
    args: ['.'],
  });

  return this.app.start();
};

const afterEach = function () {
  if (this.app && this.app.isRunning()) {
    return this.app.stop();
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

*.e2e.js*-files

```
describe('test case', function () {
  beforeEach(testUtils.beforeEach);
  afterEach(testUtils.afterEach);

  it('should run', function () {
  });
});
```

**How to store screenshots of Spectron test failures**

If you got your tests running, but they are for some reason failing, then it can be helpful to get a screenshot from the Electron application.

*utils.js*

```
const fs = require('fs');
const saveErrorShot = function (e) {
  const filename = `errorShot-${this.test.parent.title}-${this.test.title}-${new Date().toISOString()}.png`
    .replace(/\s/g, '_')
    .replace(/:/g, '');

  this.app.browserWindow.capturePage().then(imageBuffer => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, imageBuffer, error => {
      if (error) throw error;

      console.info(`Screenshot saved: ${process.cwd()}/${filename}`);
    });
  });

  throw e;
};
```

*.e2e.js*-files

```
describe('test case', function () {
  it('should store a screenshot', function () {

    return this.app.client
      .then(() => this.app.client.getText('.non-existing-element')
      .catch(testUtils.saveErrorShot.bind(this));
  });
});
```

**To make Travis send your artifacts to an Amazon S3 bucket**

Add your AWS S3 credentials to your Travis env variables, [read here for more information](https://github.com/travis-ci/artifacts).

Add the following to *.travis.yml*

```
after_failure:
  - curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/artifacts/master/install | bash
  - artifacts upload $(git ls-files -o | grep -Fv -e node_modules)
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then artifacts upload $(ls /home/travis/.npm/_logs/); fi
```

What it does is that it

1. Downloads and installs [travis-artifacts](https://github.com/travis-ci/artifacts)
2. Uploads all untracked files in your repository, but excluding all node modules. Probably you'll have some other files you want exclude, then just append `-e unnecessary_folder -e unnecesarry_file`.
3. Uploads the npm logs from `/home/travis/.npm/_logs`. If you're running MacOS the files will appear in another folder.

Answer (score -1):

The answer it's in this issue:

https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/170